# What is the meaning of "you go"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What are the meanings of the following phrases?

> In you go.

> Off you go.

> Here you go.

> There you go.

Does ‘you go’ mean the same in the phrases above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are imperatives (*Go in!*) made to sound more informal. Someone might also say "In you go!" while, for example, lifting a small child into a seat or a bath, as a friendly commentary on what they are doing.

"Here you go" and "There you go" (or "There you are") are just things you say when handing something to someone. The *you go* part doesn't have a clear meaning.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-you-go

Comment: are you saying that "in you go" is informal version of "go in"? "of you go" as well?

Comment: Yes, "In you go!" is either an instruction to go into somewhere or, as I explained, a comment on someone going in.

Comment: (I took too long on the previous comment.) You would say "Off you go!" when instructing someone to leave, either on an errand or because you want them to go away,

Comment: You could say 'off you go!' when you want someone to commence doing something, e.g. recite something, or start some task.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHarvey. Part of the reason why I took a long time writing my earlier comments was that I was trying to think how to express that meaning too.